# keras tuner AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'Metric'

Tags: keras, tuner

When I use keras Tuner for tuning, tuner=RandomSearch(hypermodel=model,objective='mse',seed=42,max_trials=3,directory=r'E:\multivariate test\bayes',project_name=' helloworld') reported an AttributeError: module'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.metrics' has no attribute'Metric', error，how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using TF v < 2.2. You can check this page [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric]. There you can find this: **tf.keras.metrics.Metric**